# "Todo lo demás son tonterías"

Tags: modismos, conjugación, nombres-colectivos

Hoy me topé con un anuncio de una gran cadena de tiendas de aparatos electrodomésticos, cuyo lema (entre otros) es :

> Todo lo demás son tonterías

¿Es gramaticalmente correcto en este caso tener un sujeto en singular con un verbo en plural? ¿O es un error intencional para dar un significado particular?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La RAE explica esto en su sección de [concordancia](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XEVeLzVZaD6CG25cW5). En el apartado 4.7 se habla de los nombres colectivos. Estos nombres son los que se refieren a un conjunto de cosas pero aparentemente el sustantivo está en singular. Normalmente estos nombres llevan un verbo en singular cuando son sujeto, pero cuando se usan **con el verbo ser y un sustantivo como atributo estos se conjugan en plural**:

> 4.7. Sujeto de nombre colectivo.
>
> ...
>
> En las oraciones **copulativas** con
> **ser** cuyo **atributo** no es un adjetivo, sino un **sustantivo**, **tanto el
> verbo como el atributo van en plural**: «Esta gente son asesinos»
> (Universal [Ven.] 7.4.97); pero si el atributo es un adjetivo, es
> incorrecta la concordancia en plural: «La gente aquí son desordenados»
> (Santiago Sueño [P. Rico 1996]); debió decirse La gente aquí es
> desordenada

Por lo tanto, cuando "todo lo demás" se refiere a un conjunto de cosas, lo correcto es decir:

> Todo lo demás son tonterías.
>
> Todo lo demás es tontería.** (incorrecto)

En un comentario en esta misma página se comenta que nunca se diría:

> Todo lo demás son inútiles** (incorrecto)
>
> Todo lo demás es inútil

En este caso se usa el singular porque "todo lo demás" no se refiere a un conjunto de cosas (no tiene sentido colectivo), sino al "esfuerzo restante" que no se puede dividir en unidades para considerarlo un plural. Además, "inútiles"/"inútil" podría considerarse un adjetivo en lugar de un sustantivo dependiendo del contexto lo que obligaría a usarlo en singular.

Answer (score 2):

Nosotros mismos usamos esa misma frase de esa misma forma, al decir "Todo lo demás" nos referimos directamente a un conjunto de cosas, con lo cual, el sujeto pasa a estar en plural, y por eso se continua con "son tonterías".

No soy experto en gramática castellana, ni mucho menos, pero es lo que he comido toda la vida.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Un saludo.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Spanish.StackExchange!

Comment: Pero no dirías `Todo lo demás son inutiles`, más bien `Todo lo demás es inútil`, o sea que el plural no es siempre obligarorio...

Comment: Ahí tienes razón, pero supongo que suena igual de feo 'Todo lo demás es tontería' de hecho en mi vida había oído a nadie usar esa expresión, yo siempre he oído 'Todo lo demás son tonterías' y 'Todo lo demás es inútil', podríamos estar hablando de un caso de 'Uso del castellano', una regla escrita o no sobre como expresarse para según que oraciones. Obviamente la oración que planteas es algo utilizado en momentos puntuales, y muy utilizada en la forma que te ha presentado la duda. Como yo no soy un letrado en esto, le he pasado la duda a la RAE a ver que me dicen ellos.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon mi respuesta quzás te aclare la duda.